# Question about Forward Price + Constant Interest Rate Approximations

Tags: black-scholes, implied-volatility

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but I'm reading the following paper *An Explicit Implied Volatility Formula*, Dan Stefanica, Rados Radoicic, International Journal of Theoretical and Applied Finance, Vol. 20, no. 7, 2017

I have some questions about the formula. https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2908494

The formula has the following:

- $C_m$ = market price of call option
- $K$ = option strike
- $T$ = option maturity
- $F$ = forward price at T of underlying asset
- $r$ = constant interest rate

Output:

- $\sigma_{\text{imp,approx}}$ = implied volatility approximation

  1. What is the "constant interest rate" ? Is it the annualized risk-free rate? If not, how can I approximate/solve for it?
  2. Considering that I am solving for the implied volatility of stocks, can I approximate the forward price of an underlying asset with:
     $$
     F_t = S_t×(1+r_f)^{T}
     $$

Answer (score 1):

1. yes.
2. Assuming that $r$ and $r_f$ are the same, you should use continuous compounding:

$$
F(t,T)=S_te^{r_f(T-t)}
$$

and if the underlying is a dividend paying instrument, then 
$$
F(t,T)=S_te^{(y-r_f)(T-t)}
$$

with $y$ the annualized continuous dividend yield.